# how to check the uniqueness of two attributes when inserting in mongodb

Tags: mongodb-query

Here's my sample schema:

```
var movieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: type: String
, rating: String
, releaseYear: Number
, region: String
});
```

I've used

```
db.movies.ensureIndex({ title: 1},{unique:true})
```

The above code will restrict any insertion incase we already have a same title name, I want to restrict insertion based upon the two things i.e  I would allow the insertion of a movie which have same name but different regions but disable insertion if both the attributes are same.

```
example 1 :   title: X-men, region: WW       &  title: X-men region: ASIA      #allowed
example 2 :   title: X-men, region: WW       &  title: X-men region: WW        #not allowed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable a [unique](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/) constraint on a [compound index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/#index-type-compound) of `title` and the `region` fields.

```
db.movies.ensureIndex( { title: 1, region: 1 }, { unique: true } )
```